# Print a horizontal line in python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to print a horizontal line in python.
basically I want to print:

actual

"----------"

Expected

but I want the '----' to be continuous.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do it with underscores (i.e "____") instead of dashes ("---"). It's not continuous, but its better than dashes.

Comment: Do you mean print to console? It depends on your font whether or not multiple underscores appear connected or not.

Comment: good answer for a poorly asked question.

Comment: ____ is not good because it is show in the bottom of the line instead of middle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try printing out using the following:

```
print('─' * 10)  # U+2500, Box Drawings Light Horizontal
print('─' * 10)  # U+2501, Box Drawings Heavy Horizontal
print('―' * 10)  # U+2015, Horizontal Bar
print('_' * 10)  # Underscore
```

Output

```
──────────   U+2500, Box Drawings Light Horizontal
──────────   U+2501, Box Drawings Heavy Horizontal
――――――――――   U+2015, Horizontal Bar
__________   Underscore
```

Take a look at the [Box-drawing character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) Wikipedia page for more bars you can use

Comment: The precise result will depend on the font used in the console. There is no portable way to really be sure that the glyphs connect properly and are aligned as the OP wishes.

Answer (score 12):

If you would like to print a horizontal line across the terminal the width of the terminal, you can use:

```
import os
term_size = os.get_terminal_size()
print('=' * term_size.columns)
```

Comment: This does not work from PyCharm. `term_size = os.get_terminal_size()` causes `OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid`.

Answer (score 5):

You could try printing extended ASCII characters as in the below example. Here the ASCII value `u'\u2500'` relates to hyphen without spaces at start and end. The `\u` specifies the following string is in extended ASCII form and `2500` denotes the `─` symbol.

```
print(u'\u2500' * 10)
```

**Result**

```
──────────
```

Comment: You don't need a loop; `print('\u2500' * 10)`

Comment: U+2550 is a double stroke ═ like =.

Comment: @tripleee perfect. I felt U+2500 is more relevant for this question

Comment: I commented on that because you have a typo where it says 2550. The `u'...'` prefix is redundant in Python 3. You probably also want to take out the `end=''` now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226814/discussion-between-swadhikar-and-tripleee).